# How to structure a graph database to support 3-way relationships?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, orientdb, titan

I've been trying to figure out a database backend for a personal webapp I've been working on. Due to the flexibility that I require in the data, a relational database isn't feasible and some form of document storage is likely. When I learned about graph databases, I felt that this would be perfect.

However, I've run into someone of an issue: I need to be able to define a 3-way relationship in some way. I haven't decided on a database yet, but I've been tinkering with Neo4j, so I'll use Cypher to describe the problem.

Essentially, I start out with this:

```
(a:N)-[r:E]->(b:N)
```

What I need is a way to relate multiple nodes to not only a and b, but also r. These other nodes are going to be storing different pieces of information about all 3. I decided that there are probably only two ways to handle this: store the relationship in its own node or store references to the nodes containing the information and create pseudo-edges. I figure that the former is probably a better idea giving us something more like this:

```
(a:N)<-[:E]-(r:R)->[:E](b:N)
(s:S)->(a)
(s)->(r)
(s)->(b)
```

So, now, this leads to an issue with querying the data. The whole point of using a graph database is being able to traverse the graph. If I do something like this, is there a way to recursively traverse between nodes of type N? What is the proper way of handling this? I've thought of several different ways of handling this, but all of them have their faults. Is there a specific graph database that supports this type of functionality natively?

**UPDATE**

With the original code, I was able to recursively traverse the nodes with this code:

```
MATCH (a:N)-[:E*]->(b:N)
RETURN a,b
```

However, once I pull the edge out into a hyperedge, I can't figure out if there is a way to be able to traverse the graph recursively to an undetermined depth because I would be alternating node types. I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
MATCH chain=((a:N)-[]->(r:R)-[]->(b:N))*
RETURN [nodes of type N along the chain]
```

If the answer is just to also create an edge between a and b while creating the hyper edge, then my question becomes: is there a good way to ensure that the edge and hyper edge are removed together? Basically, having both feels like a work-around rather than an actual solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scenario you describe is handled in property graph model by the hyperedge pattern @Pangea mentioned.  You essentially convert the edge (that needs edges in/out of it) to a vertex.  With graphs I would think of it less as a denormalization and more of a different modelling abstraction.

As far as native support for edges on edges go, none of the graphs you tagged your question with directly support such a feature.  As you did include Titan and OrientDB I assume you are evaluating TinkerPop as a possible part of your solution as well and I can further say that as Blueprints doesn't support edges on edges, none of the Blueprints graphs will either.

As far as traversal goes, I can't say I fully follow what you mean by "recursively traverse".  If you could elaborate a bit, I could try to amend my answer.  I'll add this simple example of how you would traverse from the "a" vertex to find all other related vertices in Gremlin (sorry, I don't know Cypher):

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> va = g.addVertex([type:'N',name:'a'])
==>v[0]
gremlin> er = g.addVertex([type:'R',name:'r'])
==>v[1]
gremlin> vb = g.addVertex([type:'N',name:'b'])
==>v[2]
gremlin> vc = g.addVertex([type:'N',name:'c'])
==>v[5]
gremlin> va.addEdge('e',er)
==>e[3][0-e->1]
gremlin> vb.addEdge('e',er)
==>e[4][2-e->1]
gremlin> vc.addEdge('e',er)                   
==>e[6][5-e->1]
gremlin> va.out.in.except([va]).name
==>c
==>b
gremlin> vd = g.addVertex([type:'N',name:'d'])
==>v[7]
gremlin> es = g.addVertex([type:'R',name:'s'])
==>v[8]
gremlin> vb.addEdge('e',es)
==>e[9][2-e->8]
gremlin> vd.addEdge('e',es)
==>e[10][7-e->8]
gremlin> x=[];va.aggregate(x).out.in.except(x).loop(4){it.loops<2}.name
==>c
==>b
gremlin> x=[];va.aggregate(x).out.in.except(x).loop(4){it.loops<3}.name
==>d
```

In regards to:

> If the answer is just to also create an edge between a and b while
>   creating the hyper edge, then my question becomes: is there a good way
>   to ensure that the edge and hyper edge are removed together?

When you remove the "hyperedge" vertex, you will automatically remove the edges connected to it, so you effectively remove them together.

Comment: I have updated the OP with more information about what I'm looking for. And I listed those three because they were the ones that came to me off the top of my head. I'm really looking for any type of database that will solve all of my issues and graph databases are the closest to that. I just haven't found the perfect one yet.

Comment: Updated my answer a bit.  Responded to how to remove a "hyperedge" given this model and expanded my code to include some "depth" that you could loop over to traverse to arbitrary depth (again, sorry...I don't know cypher).  Graphs provide for some very rich abstractions when modelling...while it may feel unnatural to use a vertex for what you thought to be an edge, it likely isn't so.  Graphs are about things and relations between things...it is sometimes the case that a "relation" itself can be thought of and modeled as a "thing" and that's fine if your domain demands it.

Comment: My question is: if I have (a:N)<-[:E]-(r:R)->[:E](b:N) then do I have to create (a)-[e:E]->(b) in order to traverse my nodes of type N recursively, i.e. go a->b->c->d or is there a way to do that the the hyper edge in between each of those nodes? Because it will now look like a->r1->b->r2->c->r3->d. If I create the hyperedge, I'm looking for a way to not have to create that ancillary edge, i.e. some way to define the new relationship between a and b as going through r so that I can then say do that X number of times.

Comment: You don't need to create the ancillary `(a)-[e:E]->(b)` to traverse recursively at least with Gremlin.  The graph I created in my example showed: a->r<-b->s<-d, which is basically analogous to your example of "a->r1->b->r2->c->r3->d" (directionality of edges and one less level of depth aside).  The example showed the recursion using `loop` to depth 1 and 2 (i.e `it.loops<2` and `it.loops<3)` in the final two lines.

Comment: Thinking on this further, if you could keep directionality of edges such that all edges point "out", then you wouldn't have an even less complex recursive traversal than what I was demonstrating as you would not have to aggregate/except steps in the traversal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a specific graph database that supports this type of functionality natively?

There is indeed! Grakn supports native hyperedges, called a `relation` in its syntax. The most concise way to match for a relation and the elements it relates looks like this:

```
match ($a, $b, $r) isa E; get;
```

Full disclosure: I work at Grakn ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Hyperedges](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-hyperedges.html) pattern in Neo4j's documentation.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I saw that earlier, but it didn't seem to solve my issue of recursion. The best I can gather is that maybe I should create an edge between a and b while also creating the relationship node which would allow for the best of both worlds. However, this would be called denormalization in a relational database, which is normally frowned upon, but seems to be shown off as a feature here, so I'm not sure I've quite got the idea.

Comment: Link is dead.  Could you provide more information on what this means please?