# What is the idiomatic way to add connected meta data to an edge using a graph database

Tags: graph-databases

I am pretty new to thinking about data in terms of graph databases and there is one aspect which I feel I am missing something fundamental about.

I am looking to understand the idiomatic way to connect an edge to another node, for the purpose of representing connected detail regarding the relationship. For example we may have two nodes representing two people, `Bob` and `Sue`, and we may have a relationship between them like so `[Bob] --Knows-- [Sue]`. Now, lets say we want to also represent places like `Picadilly Circus` and we also want to give context to *how* `Bob` and `Sue` know each other, mentally I want to do this:

```
[Bob] --knows-- [Sue]
        \--met at-- [Picadilly Circus]
```

I feel I am missing something here as nothing I have read so far seem to suggest any of the graph DB implementations I have looked at support this edge-from-an-edge relationship.

As an aside I was also looking at triple-store databases and the same question arises, and I can only think that having a 5-store database would solve the issue, but that does not exist either!

Any pointers gratefully received! Thank you.

Comment: In Neo4j, edges can have scalar properties only. Some triplestores supports RDF*.

Comment: "Some triplestores supports RDF*". Apologies, what is this significance of this part of your comment?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810418/how-to-structure-a-graph-database-to-support-3-way-relationships?rq=1

Comment: In RDF*, it is possible to write `<<:alice :married :bob>> :since :christmas` (in the [PG mode](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-rdf-star/2019Sep/thread.html#msg51)). In pure RDF, there are some [modeling approaches](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).

Answer (score 0):

Objectivity/DB is a massively scalable, distributable object/graph database that supports exactly what you want to do.

A good example is representing phone calls between two people. You don't want to create a new edge from Bob to Sue every time Bob calls Sue. What you want is something that looks like the diagram below. Objectivity/DB is a schema-based database and in the diagram, we will define the Call object type as an edge which allows it to be represented as an edge in queries. We can write complex edge qualifiers that qualify the edge in or out based on a broad range of semantics that exist in the connected data like the CallDetail objects connected to Call.

You can perform high speed queries from Bob to Sue to see if they have had any calls at all, or you can perform a query to see if they had a call (CallDetail) within a date range where the call lasted more than 30 minutes.

We've built systems like this that can ingest billions of data items per hour while running these kinds of complex queries. The query language also supports navigational queries that go out 100's of degrees.

[image]