# Graph DB and Relations from Edges

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I'm going to design simple knowledge base with Objects, Relations between them and Questions about Objects and Relations. I understand well how to do this in the RDBMS. But now I'm going to study Graph DB capabilities, in particular OrientDB.

Visual representation of what I want:

```
Vertex: Moon --> "What is the mass of the M?", etc
  |
  |
  o---> This Edge must also have 'one to many' (edge to questions) relation, e.g  
  |       "How far is the M. from the E?" etc.
  |
  | <-- Edge: Has a satellite (or stands nearby)
  |
Vertex: Earth --> "What is the age of the E?"
```

I found `Link list` and `Link set` [datatypes in the manual](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/general/Types.html), but I'm still not sure about (a) are they really what I need and (b) how should I properly represent Questions.

Need your help.

Comment: I don't use OrientDB but I have created multiple solutions similar to what you are describing here. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64214453/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-add-connected-meta-data-to-an-edge-using-a-graph-da/66280914#66280914